NGINX: How to Disable Client SSL Certificate for Specific URIs While Enforcing It for Others?
We are experiencing challenges with our NGINX configuration and could use some help. We have hosted a web application using NGINX, and our web application is protected by a client SSL certificate—without it, the website is not accessible.
We have hundreds of clients accessing our website with different URI paths. For example:
Client ABC accesses the website via https://portal.hello.com/ClientK1
Client SSS accesses the website via https://portal.hello.com/ClientK2
Requirement:
We need to disable the client SSL certificate requirement for specific clients while keeping it enabled for others.
Current Configuration:
Below is our current NGINX configuration:
server {
listen       10.10.0.133:443 ssl http2;
server_name  portal.hello.com;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/uathello_error.log;
access_log   /var/log/nginx/uathello_access.log;
server_tokens off;

ssl_certificate       /efs/hello.crt;
ssl_certificate_key   /efs/hello.key;
ssl_client_certificate  /efs/client.crt;
ssl_verify_client on;
ssl_verify_depth 1;

include /efs/nginx/folder/*.config;
}


I think openresty is a good choice, you can use lua script and redis to check a request is accessible.

We have few dependencies right now on NGINX, so we can't get rid of NGINX now.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63319420/whats-the-difference-between-openresty-and-nginx, dependencies may be not a problem.
